# Given a mapping function, define a binary operation such that the function is an isomorphism

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-isomorphism, binary-operations

I need help with understand **how to approach a question like this**.

Given a mapping function Φ: Q -> Q defined by Φ(x) = 3x - 1.

I need to define a binary operation * such that Φ is an isomorphism mapping.

(Q,•) -> (Q,*)

Where • is the usual multiplication.

This is my attempt:

Given a,b in Q:

Φ(a•b) = Φ(a)*Φ(b)

3(ab)-1 = (3a-1)*(3b-1)

I know that I must get a term containing ab on the right hand side, so * must be based in part on multiplication. We begin by trying * = •

3(ab)-1 = 9ab - 3a - 3b + 1

The right hand side is too large. To fix this, we do the following:

3(a•b) - 1 = (1/3)(9a•b - 3a - 3b + 1 + 3a + 3b - 4)
3(a•b) - 1 = 3(a•b) - 1

Then the binary operation * follows from the steps performed above, starting from •:

a*b = (1/3)(a•b + 3a + 3b -4)

However, I know that an isomorphism mapping preserves the identity. Thus, if e is the identity for •, then Φ(e) should be the identity for *.

The identity for • is 1. Thus, Φ(1) = 3•1 -1 = 2, the identity for *.

Trying this:

a*e = a

(1/3)(a•2 + 3•a + 3•2 - 4) = a

This is not a true statement.

The correct answer is (1/3)(a•b + a + b -2) which does have identity 2.

(1/3)(a•2 + a + 2 -2) = a

How did the author arrive at this solution? How should I approach such problems?
I have managed to correctly get some other results (particularly ones where the binary operation besides * is +).

Answer (score 1):

As you say, you must have
$$\Phi(ab)=\Phi(a)\ast\Phi(b).\tag{1}$$
But you want to find $x\ast y$. Let's solve $\Phi(a)=x$ and $\Phi(b)=y$.
For $\Phi(a)=x$ you need $3a-1=x$, so $a=\frac13(x+1)$. Also $b=\frac13(y+1)$. From $(1)$ you get
$$x\ast y=\Phi(ab)=3ab-1=\frac13(x+1)(y+1)-1$$
etc.

Comment: =(3a-1)*(3b-1), correct?

Comment: This makes sense, because we have x*y = Φ(a)*Φ(b), and so x must be Φ^-1(a) and the same for y and b.